# Chrome overflows iframe background outside of div?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, google-chrome, iframe

I have an iframe inside a div tag with Overflow:Hidden and a Border-Radius of 50px all around making it a circle. The iframe source is an .aspx page with a button. When the button is clicked it causes post back. On post back I have it change background color from nothing to something.

```
iframeBody.Attributes.Add("Style", "background-color:#FF9090");
```

It works perfectly in Firefox and Internet Explorer (Fine in IE!? Surprising!) But in Chrome it seems to overflow the background color forming a square. (All other content displays perfectly, it's just the background seeping out.) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Is this what you're trying to achieve?](http://jsfiddle.net/tX3Xc/) Because that works for me in Chrome. What is different in your project?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to recreate the issue using that site: http://jsfiddle.net/tX3Xc/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square you're seeing in your sample is the iframe border. You can easily remove that with styles:

```
iframe {
    border: 0;
}
```

The content of the iframe apparently overflows the containing div, when the div has `position: absolute` (or `relative`, for that matter). I'm not quite sure why that would be the case, but you could always work around that by wrapping that div in a container that contains only the div and the iframe, and move the positioning to that element:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div>
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

#outer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#outer > div {
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #D3D3D3;
}

iframe {
    border: 0;
    background-color: pink;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Having taken care of this, you'll notice that the iframe overlaps part of the border. This is the same behaviour you'd see in chrome if you were to just remove the `position: absolute`.

Now that you do have a wrapper, however, it is a small fix to also move the border to that wrapper, which will take care of that problem as well, and give you a nice circle border, that'll look the same across all modern browsers.

Note that you want to keep the `border-radius` property on *both* divs, but move the `border` property to `#outer`. Now, since the wrapper has a border, and its child does not, the wrapper will be slightly larger, so for a smooth circle, it'll also need a slightly greater border radius:

```
#outer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid #D3D3D3;
    border-radius: 55px;
}

#outer > div {
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

iframe {
    border: 0;
    background-color: pink;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LSZLj/)

Comment: I didn't even know there was a default border. (Using a style-sheet to reset values.) Still, it doesn't help with a background color: http://jsfiddle.net/tX3Xc/4/

Comment: That's apparently a `position: absolute` issue. Can't exactly tell you why, but removing it resolves the issue. Not that the result is a perfect circle either, though...

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me much as I need it to be positioned that way. Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that might not have been very helpful; I was just pointing out what I found to be going on. Knowing that, I've been able to construct some workarounds that I hope may be applicable to you. See my updated answer.

Comment: This worked pretty well! Thank you! As a weird side note, I couldn't apply the styles in a class. While Firefox could see the styles in the class, Chrome didn't pick up any styles! It only works inline! I'm starting to feel like Chrome is the new IE! lol

Comment: That sounds a bit odd. In the demo I've pasted at the bottom of my answer, the styles are not inline, and that works on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach. You can use webkit-mask-image and make a transparent PNG image to use as a mask (also works with gradients or more complex shapes of course). Currently only works in webkit browsers (Safari / Chrome etc.) but that equates to a little under 50% of people. Might be an option depending on audience.